# What is Custom Action (CA) MSI type number 98?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

We have an InstallShield setup that's failing miserably and we can't figure out why, so I'm trying to reconstruct it step-by-step. Everything was going fine until I got to the Custom Actions and Sequences. We have a bunch of Custom Actions and when I click on any of them in the right-hand pane I see MSI Type Number: 98. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372048(v=vs.85).aspx) article these only go as high as 54. Anyone have any idea what a 98 is? It's a read-only field so I can't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Custom Action MSI type number 98 stands for the following ...

- [Custom Action Type 34](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368092(v=vs.85).aspx) is for calls an executable launched with a command line
- The rest (+64) is for [CA processing options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which stands for a synchronous execution that ignores exit code and continues.